# Can't activate Seeeduino port

Tags: serial

I want to use `Seeeduino`, but I can't activate port connection for it.

To use `Seeduino` I installed Seeeduino from `Board Manager` in Arduino Studio.

And then installed `USB Serial Driver` from this binary.

http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP/MacOSX/FTDIUSBSerialDriver_v2_4_2.dmg

But somehow there is no corresponding port in `Tools` -> `Port`.
How can I activate the port?

Comment: You shouldn't have to install FTDI drivers on a modern Mac.   As for why it's missing, check the USB devices list in the system report both with it connected and not connected (you'll need to re-open the report) for something missing.  Try a different cable or USB version adapter.  Try it with a hub.  Try it without a hub...

Comment: From the beginning the port didn't exist that's why I installed the driver. The port exists when I use `Arduino Uno`, so I don't think cable or hub is the cause of problem. And I don't know what is "system report". How can I check it?

Comment: The Mac's advanced USB port could easily work with one brand of simpler USB chip and not another, so it working with an Uno proves little.

Comment: did you get it to work? This may help: https://forum.seeedstudio.com/t/seeeduino-xiao-com-port-problems/254316